# Blogger 2 - Jumpstart Labs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently learning Rails, and I've been directed to follow the Blogger2 tutorial [here](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html).

However, I've encountered a few problems. First of all, when I try to edit a file (I'm using VIM), I get a lot of errors that are like:

```
Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because it's extensions are not build. Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 1.3.2.
```

I'm pretty new to using VIM so I've no idea if it's VIM or Ruby but from search google it seems to be a Ruby problem.

Secondly, it tells me to edit the routes/config.rb file, and edit the file so it looks like:

```
Blogger::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
end
```

But these lines aren't in my config.rb, I've tried using RVM to install Rails4.0.0 and it's not changed anything.

If anyone could help me fix these two errors I'd be very grateful!

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the second error in entirety? Also, the first "error" is just a warning, and it recommends a command.

Comment: The errors appear in VIM when I start to use autocomplete, so it's a bit weird, and hard to select all the errors as they're printed all over my screen.

Comment: A vim error is very different than a Ruby error. At least isolate which of those it is.

Comment: The error is appearing in my VIM editor, but it's not a VIM error

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a problem with an addon for Vim. I deleted the addon and it went away.